# How to Automate SQL code using Python in efficient way

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by

I have a sql code which looks like this:
Database: `RedShift`

```
WITH
X as
(  
 SELECT  distinct pn , pg , ic, sr  , cm, fq , m1  , m2  , m3  , m4
 FROM table1  ORDER BY 1,2,3
),

table2 AS
 (
   Select g,p,t , avg(ss) as ss , avg(ce) as ce , sum(av) as ps
  from
 (
select distinct ic AS g , pn AS p , cm AS t , ss , cast((sum_m1/nullif(sum_m2,0)) as decimal(3,2)) as 
 ce , av
from
(
  select *
  , cast((sum(m3) over (partition by ic, pn,cm)) as decimal) as ss
  , sum(m1) over (partition by ic, pn,cm) as sum_m1
  , sum(m2) over (partition by ic, pn,cm) as sum_m2
  , cast((avg(m2) over (partition by ic, pn,cm)) as decimal) as av
  from X
  ORDER BY 1,2,3
)
order by 1,2,3
 )
 where ss is not null
  group by 1,2,3
  order by 1,2,3
  )
```

The group by value `g,p,t` changes every time and so it creates table for every new combination of `g,p,t` values.

One way to automate is dump this sql code in Python which might be inefficient:
Here is my approach-> I replace all values in list by `{}` braces
Example say:

I store all possible group by values in a list.

G=[g1,g2,g3]

P=[p1,p2,p3]

T=[t1,t2,t3]

Connection to databse:

```
   c= psycopg2.connect(database=db,host=host,port=port,user=user,password=password,sslmode='require')
   data2={}

   for g in G:

     for p in P:

        for t in T:
           sqlstr=( """ WITH
                            X as
                          (  
                 SELECT  distinct pn , pg , ic, sr  , cm, fq , m1  , m2  , m3  , m4
              FROM table1  ORDER BY 1,2,3
                        ),

                  table2 AS
              Select {},{},{} , avg(ss) as ss , avg(ce) as ce , sum(av) as ps
                             from
                         (
                    select distinct ic AS g , pn AS p , cm AS t , ss , cast((sum_m1/nullif(sum_m2,0)) as decimal(3,2)) as 
                      ce , av
                          from
                  (
                       select *
               , cast((sum(m3) over (partition by ic, pn,cm)) as decimal) as ss
                , sum(m1) over (partition by ic, pn,cm) as sum_m1
               , sum(m2) over (partition by ic, pn,cm) as sum_m2
               , cast((avg(m2) over (partition by ic, pn,cm)) as decimal) as av
                      from X
                     ORDER BY 1,2,3
                       )
                   order by 1,2,3
                    )
                 where ss is not null
                   group by 1,2,3
                   order by 1,2,3
                    ), select * from table2 """).format(g,p,t)
  data2[g+"_"+p+"_"+t] = pd.read_sql_query(sqlstr, c)
```

Is there any better way to pass parameters as in above code sequence of {} should be maintained to pass parameters in order ??

Can we use some other approach other than SQL? In pythonic way?

Comment: how about [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)? `from itertools import product`, then instead of nested for loops, use `for g, p, t in product(G, P, T): ...`

Comment: Thats cool. But how about passing parameters to SQL code. Any alternative to pass parameters instead `format`

Comment: This might be helpful : https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#passing-parameters-to-sql-queries

Comment: Using format is just fine. But you could use f-strings since they look more clean (python +3.6)